# Rebind a repeater table on dropdownlist change?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was curious if it was possible to rebhind a repeater table on dropdownlist change? Say I load in a table of quiz questions. When someone changes the category based on a dropdownlist, the table rebinds with the correct questions corresponding to that category. I haven't been able to find a solution to this. It may not be possible, and I may have to switch to something like a GridView.

On page load I am binding the table dynamically from the database. Should I bind the table in a function on dropdownlist change? When you using tables you have to refresh the page to see changes, but of course its going to default back the original table. I appreciate any information! I have my table code below which is located inside of the pageload. Another reason I am considering using a GridView is because I feel like it will be easier to associate the Edit/Delete with a specific row.

```
        //Populating a DataTable from database.
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();

        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<table class='table'>");

        //Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("<th> Edit </th>");
        html.Append("<th> Delete </th>");


        html.Append("</tr>");

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td align='left'>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("<td align='left'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit</button> </td>");
            html.Append("<td align='left'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button> </td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        //Table end.
        html.Append("</table>");

        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        QuestionTable.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

Comment: Did you actually try it? What was the result? Did it break? Can you provide a [MCVE] showing it not working?

Comment: The reason I didn't post an example is because the code I am working on may be eventually classified information. I have tried yes, I was just more so wondering if anyone has been able to do this successfully or  should I try using a GridView instead.

Comment: Sure, people can do it. Just about anything is possible. Such code is basic and creating a working [MCVE] should not get you in trouble.

Comment: I have added my code for constructing the table on Page_Load. My question is really whether or not I should have this table constructed on the dropdown change or should I rather switch to using a GridView rather than a table if you think that would be easier to implement. Having it constructed on Page Load isn't going to work for what I need, because if you try to rebind the table it is going to just either add to the existing table or if you refresh the page, its going to bind the table anew.

Comment: Not so much can it be done...more so....should it be done haha

Comment: If you switch to a GridView you'll have to update a lot of code/styling I imagine.  Repeaters are great because they are flexible and allow for a lot of custom styling.  As you are building the table dynamically, I'd stick the with Repeater personally.

Comment: Now that I look at your code, I really don't even see a Repeater? You're building up a table and adding it to the placeholder, but where are you binding a Repeater?

Comment: Yeah I forgot that I ended up changing the code friday before I left, I was previously using a repeater. Do you think that I should go back to using it?

Comment: I have been playing around with a lot of different ways to try and build the table haha its been a hot minute since friday.

Comment: You should use whatever makes you happy. Stack Overflow is for solving specific programming problems, not guiding you through exact controls to use for a given situation. That drifts into "primarily opinion based" which is off-topic.

Comment: So does that code you posted actually work?  On page load, does the table get populated with the right data?

Comment: Alright my bad haha just thought I would get the opinion of a few others in the field. :))))))

Comment: JohnPete22, yes the code right now on page_load populates the table with every question I have in my database

Comment: Okay, and that GetData() function you have... Is that looking at the dropdown list SelectedValue to pass to a stored proc to ultimately get the datatable you're using to build the html table?

Comment: Side comment:  Mixing HTML and server-side code like that is going to be a nightmare to develop/tweak/maintain, especially with webforms.  If someone brought  me in to do maintenance on that, I would decline the job and walk (no...run!) away.  Are you very deep into your development cycle?  Too late to consider MVC (asp.net)?

Comment: @BBCait Updated my answer.  See if that helps or not.

Comment: Yeah I am realizing that myself, @DBro haha I am just playing around with different ways to bind the table dynamically and still be able to edit it easily. It's definitely not too late lmao I convinced my supervisor to let me use c# and asp.net, because it makes the most sense to me haha

Comment: @JohnPete22 definitely helps!!  I appreciate it! Sorry it took me awhile to get back, internet went down at work!

Comment: @DBro the project is essentially a partially functioning prototype to show something that we would like to have implemented in the future so I can change it however

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="QuestionTable" runat="server" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE-BEHIND

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

public partial class _testPWforSO :  System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Populate dropdown list first, and set the default value if we want
            PopulateCategoryDropdown();

            // Bind Question Table after, so we can access the dropdown list selected value
            BuildQuestionsTable();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        // function that gets our data via dropdown lists selected value
        return new DataTable();
    }

    private void PopulateCategoryDropdown()
    {
        // categories will be whatever datasource you use to populate dropdown list
        Collection<object> categories = new Collection<object>();
        this.ddlCategories.DataSource = categories;
        this.ddlCategories.DataBind();
        // this.ddlCategories.SelectedValue = "";
    }

    protected void BuildQuestionsTable()
    {
        //Populating a DataTable from database.
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();

        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<table class='table'>");

        //Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("<th> Edit </th>");
        html.Append("<th> Delete </th>");


        html.Append("</tr>");

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td align='left'>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("<td align='left'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit</button> </td>");
            html.Append("<td align='left'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button> </td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        //Table end.
        html.Append("</table>");

        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        QuestionTable.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }

    protected void ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildQuestionsTable();
    }
}
```